# Skip moving of files with illegal characters in Ubuntu system

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, filter, operating-system

I'm moving some files in the Ubuntu system, which is currently moving all files with or without extension in a folder

Following is the command i'm using :

```
find /abc/xyz -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /mno/pqr
```

But now I want to move files only after applying some filter :

- If file contains an "_" (underscore), I would like to skip that file movement.
- I would like to have a parameter flag, which when 0 or 1, would enable to overrite files with same name at the destination.

Can somebody please help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

1. > If file contains an "_" (underscore), I would like to skip that file movement.

   You could try this

   ```
   find /abc/xyz -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*_*' -exec mv {} /mno/pqr
   ```

   `! -name '*_*'` will skip all files which have a '_' in their names. If you have more than one illegal characters to check, you could add one test (such as `! -name '*_*'`) for each of these characters.
2. > I would like to have a parameter flag, which when 0 or 1, would enable to overrite files with same name at the destination.

   - `mv -n`  do not overwrite an existing file
   - `mv -f`  do not prompt before overwriting

Comment: +1. How to check if i've a set of illegal characters. one of them is "_". How to check for others ?

Comment: @peeppeep You may need to add one test for each of your illegal characters, like what you did for '*'.

Comment: thanks for quick ans. Could u please help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164358/getting-response-from-shell-command-to-java-code